# How to use ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject in Windows Phone 8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an app in Windows Phone 8.1 RT which uses methods from [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) However when I used "ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject", the Visual Studio (ver 2015 Update 1) replied that "Thread Pool does not contain a definition for RegisterWaitForSingleObject" So what is the problem in here? Please help me!

Update: I ask this because following this link, they noted that I can use all of these materials on Windows Phone 8.1 RT, but when I used, I did not work, so I posted the question in here and look for a help for the replacement or kind of.

P/s: If someone vote down the question, I think we should know who is he/she, they have to take their own responsibility which their decision, instead of blaming other without any identities. I apologize for posting my opinion and my question in one thread but I do not know where can I send my opinion to moderators, thanks for reading this!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this method doesn't supported in WinRT. Only on Silverlight for Windows Phone or Windows 10 UWP. You can check this in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02x3daw5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Try using WebRequest instead:

```
public async void SomeFunction()
{
    WebRequest myWebRequest=WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
    WebResponse myWebResponse=await myWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
    //do your code
}
```

Comment: Let me try but are there any solution for converting these codes into Runtime https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: @iamatsundere181 what difficulty did you meet? And i guess it better to ask it in different question.

Comment: Btw, I found another solution but I am think about posting it as a answer of not.